# Error while changing the orientation in my android phone.

Tags: android, runtime-error

I have added an option to apply different theme for my android phone. while applying i am starting an async task. If i change the orientation while applying it i am getting an Error which is given below.

```
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.ThemeSettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.ThemeSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1994)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3375)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1153)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.ThemeSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3004)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2458)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     ... 13 more
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at com.android.settings.ThemeSettingsActivity.onActivityResult(ThemeSettingsActivity.java:308)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3000)
01-01 00:19:25.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3553):     ... 14 more
```

I am not able to find the reason of this please help.

Comment: is your package `com.android.settings`?

Comment: Yea com.android.settings is my package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ted said, you're probably getting bitten by poor AsyncTask usage. I wrote a blog entry on AsyncTask pitfalls. You might find it relevant to your situation.

http://www.shanekirk.com/2012/04/asynctask-missteps/

-Shane

Comment: Nice presentation of the issue, and it's easier than reading through the Google groups discussion. I left a comment on your blog about a problem still remaining.

Comment: Thanks for the blog. I have another problem. if the user presses the home button while applying the theme the Icons are not changing. What i am doing is, in my async task i am storing the theme resources (Icons) into the database and refreshing the phone by sending an custom intent from the onPostExecute() so the Icons will refresh. But the user interrupts the async task then it is not happening. Is there any way to overcome this ?

Answer (score 5):

It would help to see your code, particularly the `onActivityResult` method of ThemeSettingsActivity.java that includes line 308.

However, there's a weakness in the design of AsyncTask that might account for this. When you change orientation, your activity is destroyed and recreated. However, the AsyncTask (especially if it is an inner class of the activity) is still interacting with the destroyed activity. The Android docs suggest saving the task state and destroying the task when the activity is being destroyed, and then constructing a new task from the saved state when the activity is recreated. See [this discussion thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!starred/android-developers/vwRrlc84gy0) on Google Groups, where several ideas are discussed for working around the problem in a way that allow the task to continue.